# Python simple login

Tags: python, python-3.x, login-script

I have assignment in my school to create function with simple login from some file (users.txt) I'm not very good at Python 3.5 so I need help.

---

Data in users.txt looks like this:

**Name|Surname|username|password**

separated by "|"

---

My job is to create simple login when program starts and continue to *main_menu()* if username and password input matches with one in *users.txt* file.

Thx :)

ps. I'm not supposed to use any advanced methods for login :(

Comment: Dont post  WRITE ME CODE FOR THIS on stackoverflow, if you want that use freelancer or some other site like that

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic I'm sorry, I didn't know that I have to pay to learn how to do something :( it supposed to be a question not "write me code" question ... (jbg nemam koga da pitam u ovo doba)

Comment: @FrankieD, if you had a question, it wasn't very clear. As written, it looks very much like a "do my homework for me" request. You don't have to pay to learn how to do something, but you do have to put in some effort.

Comment: @FrankieD http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Mora da napises sta si pokusao, ne samo da kazes "treba mi ovo".
Uz to sta si pokusao ako imas gresku napisi svoj kod da vidimo i napisi koja je tacno greska. :)
I najbitnije : kad ti neko odgovori daj mu upvote i prihavti odgovor  :D

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic a jbg noob, tek sam se reg :) jesam, sve odgovore sam upvote mada i nakon ovih dole predloga nesto mi ne radi kako treba. Mada nije ni vazno, tako je kad cekas zadnji cas pa radis programiranje u 3 sata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main_menu():
    print('successfull login!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_name = input('Enter user name:')
    password = input('Enter password:')

    f = open('users.txt')
    file_content = f.read()
    users = file_content.split('\n')
    print(users)
    for user in users:
        user_array = user.split('|')
        current_username = user_array[2]
        current_password = user_array[3]
        if (current_username == user_name and current_password == password):
            main_menu()
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for helping. :) @YuvalPruss

Answer (score 0):

Use [getpass:](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html)

```
import getpass

while(True):
    print("FrankieD's simple Python Login Tool")
    print("===================================")
    user_name = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()

    with open('users.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            row = line.split('|')
        if((user_name.lower() == row[2].lower()) and (password == row[3])):
            print("Logged on as %s" % (user_name))
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect password or username, Please try again...\n")
```